# Android Bluetooth MAP

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a question for somebody who ever worked with **Bluetooth MAP on Android**.

Can an external device (implementing MAP profile), access emails information on Android devices, via Bluetooth MAP ?

I am searching for this information to create a specification, and I can't really find anything about this.

I found that there are lots of android devices that are not supporting map at all.

And the most tricky part is that I found in MAP specification, that it should be able to query email inbox, but android does not expose anything related to email (via Content provider or something else).

Can somebody point me to a specification or something that might help?

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, external devices(often carkits) can access phone email information, in MAP spec , check  SdP record section in spec in which we need to mention which all message types are to be supported by MSE(MAP server), if email bit is set , MAP server needs to support Email messages as well.

Folder listing/ Message listing is a standard operation in MAP, for MAP email implementation i would recommend you to check in codeaurora site.

Comment: I read the section in which is described that, but I've tried on htc one one it seems that only sms is supported... that's why I'm asking. And I know that Android default email client has no public content provider to expose data. So... does that means that MAP protocol bypass application's sandbox?

Comment: check this [link](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/external/gigabyte/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/tree/src/com/android/bluetooth/map?h=jb_2.1.3.7) , do check BluetoothMasAppEmail.java file which will give you more insight on MAP email implementation .. HTC would have its own implementation.....